# How to say better "makes me have to"?

Tags: grammar

The sentence is

> and my camera constantly refocuses, **it makes me have to wait** 5 seconds before it finally focuses.

The bold part is what sounds weird to me but I have no idea what's a better way of saying it without losing the meaning.

Comment: A better way is perhaps "so I have to wait 5 seconds ..." or just leave out the fluff: "it makes me wait 5 seconds ..."

Comment: Welcome! One of the challenges of Stack Exchange is figuring out which site your question is on-topic for. May I ask, are you an English language learner? If so, there's a separate [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange that might be more helpful. The only grammatical error in this sentence is comma splice, but it could definitely be reworded more efficiently. However, writing advice is probably better suited to the [Writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/) site (though requests to rephrase material might be off-topic there too).

Comment: Try, _so it takes 5 seconds to get a clear image_. Shorter is better.

Comment: Other options that would fit in the fragment of a sentence that you provide are "forcing me to wait," "compelling me to wait," and "requiring me to wait."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shorter version is the following, though I wish we had the beginning of the sentence:

"and my camera constantly refocuses, making me wait 5 seconds before it finally focuses."

Comment: Thanks, "making me wait" sounds much better. The beginning of the sentence was "When using the scan function my camera..." I put the "and" there for simplicity sake...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short form that is used for both inanimates and people.

- and my camera constantly refocuses, it **has me waiting** 5 seconds before it finally focuses.

Plenty of examples can be found on this [page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22has%20me%20waiting%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can shorten this  if you agree the reader understands what you are waiting for.

> ... and my camera constantly refocuses, costing me five seconds
> each time.